# Can a voltage divider be used to safely lower pull-up voltage?

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider, pullup, open-drain

I'm working with an [LTC2950](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/295012fd.pdf) pushbutton on/off chip that's meant to toggle the enable pins of voltage regulators based presses from a momentary pushbutton. The LTC's enable pin is open drain and is specified to only operate in a 0V~10V range. The device is being powered by 12V, so until the regulator's are enabled, I only have 12V to pull up with.

Can I use a voltage divider to lower the pull-up voltage to appropriate levels directly, or do I need to use additional components or some other method entirely to use the available voltage to provide a pull-up within the specified range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly, you are trying to limit the potential that the EN pin of the LTC2950 is ever is exposed to, to +10V, since this is the maximum permitted for that pin of that device.

This is a valid concern, if the only voltage available for the pull-up resistor (on this open-drain output) exceeds 10V. The answer is yes, you may use a resistor potential divider to overcome this issue, as shown on the left here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWQ7wm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The middle and right arrangements show M1 replaced by a switch, representing the off and on states of the transistor. As you can see, the potential at X is indeed constrained to be less than 10V.

Since you are driving the shutdown/enable input of a regulator, you don't necessarily require this potential to be 10V when high, you just need enough potential to be compatible with the regulator's own digital switching thresholds.

For instance, the LP2951 [(datasheet)](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvsaw6b/slvsaw6b.pdf) has a shutdown pin, and we are told on page 6 that this pin requires 2V to be interpreted as "high". On that same page though, we are also told that the pin could sink up to 750μA under certain conditions. In other words, any EN voltage (node X above) between 2V and 10V would be fine, but you must also ensure that it remains above 2V with 750μA of current being drawn by the regulator's digital input.

Here I divide by two, and load the divider output with 750μA:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEO9u4.png)</sup>

Without any load, we would expect +6V at node X, easily sufficient to operate the shutdown pin of the regulator, but on the left we see that voltage drop perilously close to the +2V limit, under a 750μA load. To be safe, on the right I have used smaller resistances to reduce the signal's source impedance, so that the load doesn't influence that voltage so much.

Another way to limit the potential of an open drain or collector, is to clamp using a zener diode:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4gsIL.png)</sup>

The 5.1V diode D1 ensures that X can never rise above 5V or so, regardless of the supply potential. It will regulate better too, a big help if there is any possibility that the 12V supply may rise sufficiently high to take a resistor potential divider output beyond the 10V limit, or fall far enough to cause X to drop below the 2V minimum.

The simple resistor divider is a perfectly good solution, though, and cheaper, if you're sure that the 12V supply is reasonably stable.

Comment: This might be the best breakdown for one of my questions I've seen yet. Many thanks. I'm planning to supply the 12V through an AC-DC wall adapter, so I'm leaning towards the Zener option, if only to err on the side of caution. That said, it's good to know that the simple voltage divider is an option

Comment: Any specific traits beyond Zener voltage that I should be on the lookout for?

Comment: @E.HP.S Even the lowest power zener would be fine with such low currents, so any zener would work here.

Comment: Thanks. It probably would be a good idea too to include the option for pulling up the PB pin as well, just in case. The datasheet mentions the possibility, and it's probably better to have that option than be caught with your pants down

Answer (score 1):

A resistor voltage divider is a fine way to pull up an open drain, or open collector, or input pin, when the voltage available is too high.

One drawback is that this method will draw a constant extra current, over and above what the desired pull-up resistor and open drain, open collector or input pin would draw.  We will quantify in a moment.

Here is a schematic of the circuit we wish we had, a circuit using the available voltage rail and a voltage divider, and a circuit representing the constant current drawn over what our desired circuit would have drawn.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f96f13.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Those familiar with Thevenin Equivalents will see that our desired circuit is just the Thevenin equivalent of the voltage divider circuit.

We can calculate the values of \$R_{top}\$ and \$R_{bottom}\$ from our \$V_{desired}\$, \$V_{available}\$ and \$R_{desired}\$.

$$R_{top} = R_{desired}\frac{V_{available}}{V_{desired}}$$

and

$$R_{bottom} = R_{desired}\frac{V_{available}}{V_{available}-V_{desired}}$$

The extra current drawn by using the voltage divider circuit rather than the desired circuit will be

$$I_{extra} = \frac{V_{available}}{R_{top}+R_{bottom}}$$

And the extra power dissipated is

$$P_{extra} = I_{extra}V_{available}$$

---

As an example, suppose you want to create a voltage divider that is equivalent to a 10 k\$\Omega\$ resistor connected to a 9 V source, but you only have a 12 V source. Then use:

$$R_{top} = 10000\frac{12}{9} = 13.333 k\Omega$$

$$R_{bottom} = 10000\frac{12}{12-9} = 40k\Omega$$

The voltage divider will constantly draw an extra current

$$I_{extra} = \frac{12}{13333+40000} = 225 uA$$

Which will result in extra power dissipation of

$$P_{extra} = 0.225 m \times 12 = 2.7 mW$$

Comment: Great breakdown of the math! Honestly, I really wish you could accept more than one answer to a question, especially if they complement one another, like yours and Simon Fitch's do.